# What's the best way to protect certain records from modification or deletion?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models: user, subscription, and channel.

User:

```
has_many :channels, :through => :subscriptions
```

Subscription:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :channel
```

Channel

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :users, :through => :subscriptions
```

I have an `after_create` method that automatically adds the creating user of a channel to the subscriptions table with some other necessary attributes set. How and where should I add the prevention of the deletion or modification of subscription record that corresponds to the the channel's user?

Because my models can be updated from a few different actions in different controllers, I need this in the model layer, but I'm not sure which callback I should use. Do I need to write a validation or do I need to hook in to `before_destroy`, `after_destroy` or what?

Rails 3.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to prevent the deletion or modification of the `Subscription` record unless certain criteria are met, I'd put those protections in the `Subscription` model's `before_destroy` and `before_save` hooks. If your criteria for modifying and deleting are the same they can both point to the same method; otherwise you can specify `before_destroy :validate_destroy_privileges` and `before_save validate_save_privileges`, or whatever makes semantic sense to what you're checking.

Comment: It was a little more difficult to set up because users get added on a nested form via a username. However, forcing the existence of the channel creator's subscription with the administrator attribute set to true. Here are my models. https://gist.github.com/1745675